# Adding decimals to rangeslider

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the function I'm using for making the range slider:

```
function rangeSlider(id, onDrag) {

    var range = document.getElementById(id),
        dragger = range.children[0],
        draggerWidth = 20, // width of your dragger
        down = false,
        rangeWidth, rangeLeft;

    dragger.style.width = draggerWidth + 'px';
    dragger.style.left = -draggerWidth + 'px';
    dragger.style.marginLeft = (draggerWidth / 2) + 'px';

    range.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
        rangeWidth = this.offsetWidth;
        rangeLeft = this.offsetLeft;
        down = true;
        updateDragger(e);
        return false;
    });

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        updateDragger(e);
    });

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
        down = false;
    });

    function updateDragger(e) {
        if (down && e.pageX >= rangeLeft && e.pageX <= (rangeLeft + rangeWidth)) {
            dragger.style.left = e.pageX - rangeLeft - draggerWidth + 'px';
            if (typeof onDrag == "function") onDrag(Math.round(((e.pageX - rangeLeft) / rangeWidth) * 100));
        }
    }

}


// Run!

rangeSlider('range-slider-1', function(value) {
    document.getElementById('test-result').innerHTML = value + '%';
});

rangeSlider('range-slider-2', function(value) {
    document.getElementById('test-result').innerHTML = value + '%';
});
```

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/yuvekecodo/edit?html,js,output

How can I have the output in decimals?

For example if I set the range from 10 - 100 I want it to be able to have the decimals. 10.01, 10.02, 10.03 ~ 99.97. 99.98, 99.99, etc.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks guys, I'm loosing my mind over this for days.

Cheers.

Thanksl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this may help to get 2 digit decimal point values:

```
if (typeof onDrag == "function") onDrag(parseFloat(((e.pageX - rangeLeft) / rangeWidth) * 100).toFixed(2));
```

Use it for like:

```
 function updateDragger(e) {
    if (down && e.pageX >= rangeLeft && e.pageX <= (rangeLeft + rangeWidth)) {
        dragger.style.left = e.pageX - rangeLeft - draggerWidth + 'px';
        var startpnt=10,endpnt=50,baseval_percent,baseval;
        baseval_percent = ((e.pageX - rangeLeft) / rangeWidth) * 100;
        baseval = (endpnt-startpnt)*baseval_percent/100;
        baseval = baseval+startpnt;
      if (typeof onDrag == "function") onDrag(parseFloat(baseval).toFixed(2)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check updated function that will display `startpnt=10` and `endpnt=50` value based on percentage